# Problem with CKEditor inside a ColorBox modal popup

Tags: html, css, ckeditor, colorbox

Please can anyone help me out. I have an html page in which I have added a modal popup from ColorBox. In the ColorBox popup, I have added a CKEditor. The problem is as follows:

In IE, the CKEditor works fine, but in FF & Chrome, I get the CKEditor like in readonly mode (I can't type anything in it).
If i put the CKEditor directly into the page (and not in the modal popup), it works fine in all browsers.

I think this might be a problem with the z-index on one of the elements generated by CKEditor. But I don't know which one exactly?

I would really appreciate some help plz, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

We got around our problem by switching lightboxes, rather than use ColorBox, use Simple Modal.  I have a funny feeling it will work for you.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    initCKEditor(); //function ckeditor.
    $("#id_textarea").val(CKEDITOR.instances.id_textarea.getData());
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Render/create ckeditor on colorbox *"onComplete"* callback.

See callbacks here : http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox

Answer (score 0):

After some debugging I found that it is because of a CSS rule.

In the skin named `kama` you need to change the following CSS rule in `mainui.css` from:

```
.cke_skin_kama .cke_browser_ie.cke_browser_quirks .cke_contents iframe
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

To:

```
.cke_skin_kama .cke_browser_ie.cke_browser_quirks .cke_contents iframe
{
    top: 0;
}
```

Depending on your setup, you might need to change it in `skins/kama/editor.css`

I however recommend upgrading to a newer version of ckeditor.  I found this issue on version 3.6.2.